# Update table view UI whenever there is a change in a object of observable list JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a DataModel that contain ObservableList of an object.

```
public class ExtractDataModel {
    private final ObservableList<ExtractInfo> extractInfoList;    
    private final ObjectProperty<ExtractInfo> currentExtractInfo = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);
    
    public ObservableList<ExtractInfo> getExtractInfoList(){
        return extractInfoList;
    }
    
    public final void setExtractInfoList(ObservableList<ExtractInfo> _extractInfoList){
        extractInfoList.setAll(_extractInfoList);
    }

    getters, setters ...


    public ExtractDataModel(){
          extractInfoList = FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<>(),ExtractInfo.extractor());
    }

}
```

My controller

```
public class ExtractTabController {
    private ExtractDataModel extractDataModel;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ExtractInfo, Double> progressCol;
    @FXML
    private TableView<ExtractInfo> extractTable;
    
    other columns ...

    public void initialize() {
      extractTable.setItems(sortedExtractInfoList);
      progressCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ExtractInfo, Double>("progress"));
      progressCol.setCellFactory(ProgressBarTableCell.<ExtractInfo>forTableColumn());
    }

   public ExtractTabController(ExtractDataModel _extractDataModel) {
        System.out.println("Call constructor in extract controller");
        this.extractDataModel = _extractDataModel;
    }

}
```

`ExtractInfo's extractor` is defined as below

```
public class ExtractInfo {
    private final StringProperty tableName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty fields = new SimpleStringProperty();
    other fields ...
    private DoubleProperty progress = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    public DoubleProperty getProgressProperty() {
        return this.progress;
    }

    public Double getProgress() {
        return this.progress.get();
    }

    public void setProgress(Double progress) {
        this.progress.set(progress);
    }
    
    public static Callback<ExtractInfo, Observable[]> extractor() {
        return (ExtractInfo extractInfo) -> new Observable[]{extractInfo.getTableNameProperty(),
            extractInfo.getFieldsProperty(),
            extractInfo.getProgressProperty(),
            extractInfo.getLimitRowsPerFileProperty(),
            extractInfo.getLimitRowsProperty(),
            extractInfo.getExtractFileNameProperty(),
            extractInfo.checkBoxValueProperty()};
    }
```

My table view will use `setItems(extractDataModel.getExtracInfoList())`

My goal is that whenever there is a change in `ExtractInfo` by setters  TableView also update its UI

I created a function to test that in my data model

```
public void testUpdateUI(){
     for(ExtractInfo ei: extractInfoList){

         // Update extractInfoList but not table view UI
         ei.setProgress(Double.valueOf("1");

         // This will update table view UI - also change extractInfoList second time by remove then add new item
         //    Don't want to add this line

         extractInfoList.set(extractInfoList.indexOf(ei),ei)
     }

}
```

Can I update table view by simply using `extractInfo.setProgress()` ? Is it consider as cheating or bad practice by using above code to update table view UI?

Tried to use extractor as showing but it doesn't work.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: .. and make sure to follow fx property naming conventions (should be xxProperty not getXXProperty)

Comment: extending snippets is doesn't make them a [mcve] - yours don't even compile :) Please read the referenced help page and act accordingly (and mind the __M__ ... nobody wants to wade through tons of unrelated code: just an example data object with two or three properties)

Comment: It should work just by setting the value. Post a [mre] demonstrating the problem if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Change all getXXProperty to xxProperty will do the trick.

Here is smaller example:

```
public class ExtractDataModel {

    private ObservableList<ExtractInfo> extractInfoList;

    public ExtractDataModel() {
        
        extractInfoList = FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList(), ExtractInfo.extractor());
        ObservableList<ExtractInfo> extractInfoList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        extractInfoList.add(new ExtractInfo(0.1));
        extractInfoList.add(new ExtractInfo(0.4));
        extractInfoList.add(new ExtractInfo(0.7));
        extractInfoList.add(new ExtractInfo(0.3));
        setExtractInfoList(extractInfoList);
    }

    public ObservableList<ExtractInfo> getExtractInfoList() {
        return extractInfoList;
    }

    public void setExtractInfoList(ObservableList<ExtractInfo> _extractInfoList) {
        extractInfoList.setAll(_extractInfoList);
    }
}


public class ExtractInfo {
    private DoubleProperty progress = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    public DoubleProperty progressProperty() {
        return this.progress;
    }
    
    public Double getProgress(){       
        return this.progress.get();
    }

    public void setProgress(Double _progress) {
        this.progress.set(_progress);
    }
    
    public static Callback<ExtractInfo, Observable[]>extractor(){
        return (ExtractInfo extractInfo) -> new Observable[]{
            extractInfo.progressProperty()
        };
    }
    
    public ExtractInfo(Double _progress){
        setProgress(_progress);
    }
    
}

public class ExtractTabController {
    private ExtractDataModel extractDataModel;
    
    @FXML
    private TableView<ExtractInfo> extractTable;
    
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<ExtractInfo, Double> progressCol;
    
    public ExtractTabController(ExtractDataModel _extractDataModel){
        System.out.println("Call constructor extract tab controller");
        this.extractDataModel =  _extractDataModel;
        System.out.println(_extractDataModel.getExtractInfoList());
    }
    
    public void initialize(){
        
        progressCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ExtractInfo, Double>("progress"));
        progressCol.setCellFactory(ProgressBarTableCell.<ExtractInfo>forTableColumn());
        extractTable.setItems(extractDataModel.getExtractInfoList());
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void updateUI(){
        for(ExtractInfo extractInfo : extractDataModel.getExtractInfoList()){
            extractInfo.setProgress(1.0);
        }
    }
}

public class App extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ExtractDataModel model = new ExtractDataModel();
        
        Parent root = null;
        try {
            FXMLLoader mainFxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
            
            mainFxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("ExtractTab.fxml"));
            Callback<Class<?>, Object> controllerFactory = new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {
                ExtractTabController extractTabController = new ExtractTabController(model);
                @Override
                public Object call(Class<?> type) {
                    if (type == ExtractTabController.class) {
                        System.out.println("Return controller !");
                        return extractTabController;
                    }
                    return null;
                };        
            };
            mainFxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
            root = mainFxmlLoader.load();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            
        }
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

XML

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" fx:controller="javafxapplication2.ExtractTabController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="extractTable" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="progressCol" prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button layoutX="308.0" layoutY="157.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#updateUI" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: :)) btw: don't use propertyValueFactory at all (it's brittle even in the best of times), particularly not if your data model already exposes the properties as .. properties :)

Comment: @kleopatra What are you laughing for ?  I appreciate your support but laughing every time for nothing make me uncomfortable.

Comment: no offense meant - just happy that applying my comment to your question did indeed work for you :)